# Align three elements on Shiny dashboard

Tags: r, layout, shiny

I try to put properly three elements on my Shiny dashboard

```
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
            titlePanel("Crimes in Washington, DC (2017)"), 
            fluidRow(column(4,
                            selectInput("offenceInput", "Type of Offence",
                                        choices = 
sort(unique(incidents$OFFENSE)),
                                        selected = 
sort(unique(incidents$OFFENSE)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput("methodInput", "Method of Offence",
                                        choices = 
sort(unique(incidents$METHOD)),
                                        selected = 
sort(unique(incidents$METHOD)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput("shiftInput", "Police Shift",
                                        choices = 
sort(unique(incidents$SHIFT)),
                                        selected = 
sort(unique(incidents$SHIFT)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput('background', 'Background',
                                        choices = providers,
                                        multiple = FALSE,
                                        selected = 'Stamen.TonerLite'),
                            dateRangeInput('dateRange',
                                             label = 'Date',
                                             start = as.Date('2017-01-01') , 
end = as.Date('2017-12-31')
                              )
            ),
            
            
            column(10,
                   dataTableOutput('my_table'),
            
            column(12,
                   leafletOutput(outputId = 'map', height = 600)
            )
            )
            
))
```

My map goes somewhere else, I tried different options. Just need map in a proper right top corner and a table below.

[image: Current status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I have put all `selectInput` fields in left panel, `map` in right panel and `my_table` below these two panels. Trick is that `column`'s 1st parameter should add to 12 (i.e. 4+8 in case of top panel and 12 in case of bottom panel).

```
ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(4,
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                dateRangeInput(...)),
                         column(8,
                                leafletOutput(outputId = 'map', height = 600)),
                         column(12,
                                dataTableOutput('my_table'))))
```

**Note:** I was not able to test it due to lack of reproducible example but I hope this should work in your case.

Comment: Worked perfectly

Comment: Glad that it helped!

Comment: how to do the same for 4 objects? I would like to include a barplot under filters. Map and table remain behind.

Comment: If I understood your followup question correctly then just add barplot in 1st `column`'s entry after `dateRangeInput(...)`. This way all layout will be intact except an addition of barplot under left top panel.

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/align-four-elements-on-shiny-dashboard/7527

Comment: Looks like you have two options now :) - 1) one as I mentioned in my previous comment using one `fluidRow` and 2) other as paul7h has suggested in shiny forum using two `fluidRow`.

Comment: I am trying your option, and I am missing something, can you please add the code

Comment: `ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(4,
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                selectInput(...),
                                dateRangeInput(…),
    plotOutput(“bar_plot")),
                         column(8,
                                leafletOutput(outputId = 'map')),
                         column(12,
                                dataTableOutput('my_table'))))`

Comment: Nope, does not work for me, something is missing, now it is one column for all for elements :(

Comment: Not sure but @veegpap seems to have a working solution. Minor tweak to his solution - `ui <- fluidPage(fluidRow(column(4,
                         selectInput(...),
                         selectInput(...),
                         selectInput(...),
                         selectInput(...),
                         dateRangeInput(...)),
                  column(8, leafletOutput(outputId = 'map'))
                ),
                fluidRow(
                  column(4, plotOutput("distPlot")),
                  column(8, dataTableOutput('my_table'))
                ))`

Comment: thanks a lot for your time. Finally resolved here https://community.rstudio.com/t/align-four-elements-on-shiny-dashboard/7527/11

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with the help of RCommunity worldwide.

```
# User interface
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
            titlePanel(HTML("<h1><center><font size=14> Crimes in Washington, DC (2017) </font></center></h1>")),
            fluidRow(column(4, align="center", 
                            selectInput("offenceInput", "Type of Offence",
                                        choices = sort(unique(incidents$Offense)),
                                        selected = sort(unique(incidents$Offense)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput("methodInput", "Method of Offence",
                                        choices = sort(unique(incidents$Method)),
                                        selected = sort(unique(incidents$Method)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput("shiftInput", "Police Shift",
                                        choices = sort(unique(incidents$Shift)),
                                        selected = sort(unique(incidents$Shift)),
                                        multiple = TRUE),
                            selectInput('background', 'Background',
                                        choices = providers,
                                        multiple = FALSE,
                                        selected = 'Stamen.TonerLite'),
                            dateRangeInput('daterangeInput',
                                             label = 'Date',
                                             start = as.Date('2017-01-01') , end = as.Date('2017-12-31')
                              ),
                            br(),
                            plotOutput("bar")
            ),

            column(8,
                   leafletOutput(outputId = 'map', height = 600, width = 800),

                       dataTableOutput('my_table')

            )

))
```

This gives the following layout. It is messy, but the structure is what I really wanted. Will improved small tweaks.

[image]